# scriptler.git repository responds with 404 screen

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-scriptler

When i access the Git Repo sub-menu of the scriptler interface in jenkins using scriptler-plugin, I get a 404 screen.

When i try to add a script, I get a NPE when i try to retrieve the repository and the `JENKINS_URL/scriptler.git` is not a repository.

I've tried to run `git init` inside the <jenkins_home>/scriptler/scripts directory with no luck.

How can i initialize the scriptler git repository? As far as i know, It should already be initialized. (yes I've turned it off and on again :P)

Kind regards,
Jared.

Comment: I don't know if this might help you: I had the same 404 when accessing the <jenkins_home>/scriptler.git and the logs did not show anything relevant.  Then I discovered some of the required plugins git-client.jpi were disabled. I re-enabled them and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to fix this was to recreate the Jenkins instance completely.